# Reverse "lvconvert --splitcache"?

Tags: ubuntu, cache, volume

In order to expand a Logical Volume, I had to split the cache off from it:

```
root@server:/home# lvextend -L+50G /dev/vg1/home
  Unable to resize logical volumes of cache type.
root@server:/home# lvs
  LV      VG   Attr       LSize   Pool         Origin         Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home    vg1  Cwi-aoC--- 250.00g [homeCache]  [home_corig]   100.00 9.29            0.00            
  newvar  vg1  Cwi-aoC--- 200.00g [Cvar_cache] [newvar_corig] 100.00 0.92            0.00            
  root_lv vg1  -wi-ao----  93.07g                                                                    
  var     vg1  -wi-ao---- 120.00g                                                                    
root@server:/home# lvconvert --splitcache /dev/vg1/home
  Logical volume vg1/home is not cached and cache pool vg1/homeCache is unused.
root@server:/home# lvextend -L+50G /dev/vg1/home
  Size of logical volume vg1/home changed from 250.00 GiB (64000 extents) to 300.00 GiB (76800 extents).
  Logical volume home successfully resized.
root@server:/home# resize2fs !$
resize2fs /dev/vg1/home
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
```

How do I re-attach the split cache back to the LV? Should I have used --uncache instead to destroy the cache and then rebuild it? If so, what's my next step to destroy the old cache so it doesn't waste space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering in case someone is looking for this (or the future me):

```
lvconvert --type cache --cachepool cache-pool vg/lv
```

So in this case:

```
lvconvert --type cache --cachepool homeCache vg1/home
```

You can see all the LVs, including the caches, with:

```
lvs -a
```